# Template Toolkit and lazy Moose attributes - how to make them behave?

Tags: perl, moose, template-toolkit

If I declare lazy attribute in perl class using Moose, and the attribute is using builder:

```
has 'colors' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'ArrayRef',
  lazy => 1,
  builder => '_build_colors',
);
```

then in Template::Toolkit template I'll try to use this attribute:

```
[% FOREACH color IN colors %]
...
[% END %]
```

I'll get nothing. I have to call this attr manualy in perl script before processing the attribute with TT.
Is there any way TT can initialize this attr by himself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am assuming you are passing the Moose object like this.

```
$template->process('some.tt', $moose_object, ... );
```

The second paramater is assumed to be a hashref, not any kind of blessed object ( Moose or not ).

So, the Moose object gets treated as a plain hash and does not have the 'colors' key until you populate it by calling the accessor outside Template Toolkit.

You need to do something like this:

```
$template->process('some.tt', { obj => $moose_object }, ... );
```

And then in your template:

```
[% FOREACH color IN obj.colors %]
...
[% END %]
```

Which should work as you expect it to.

Comment: Good guess of the OP's actual error! I bet you got bitten by this before :)

Comment: @ikegami Nope, but I have spent way too much time recently working with Template Toolkit and needing to study how the stash works.

Comment: Yes, actual scheme was a little more complex, but in general your way worked for me, thanks!